# Why Flask-Login get user data across application?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

now i have multiple flask application which all application include the flask-login module for handle user login.

And now my problem is when i login at the first application, the second one also login too and as i noticed that the second application login with the user that have the same id of user table in the database. But all application using the database that separated.

And this is how my application look like.

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import sys
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecrete'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://test:1234@localhost/app1'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False # silence the deprecation warning
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'

from application import routes
```

models.py

```
from application import db, login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return Users.query.get(user_id)

class Users(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40))
    username = db.Column(db.String(80))
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
    role = db.Column(db.String(20))
    photo = db.Column(db.String(20))

    def get_id(self):
           return (self.id)
```

routes.py

```
from application import app
from flask import render_template, url_for, jsonify, request, redirect, flash
from flask_login import login_user, current_user, logout_user, login_required

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['inputUsername']
        password = request.form['inputPassword']
        user = Users.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if user:
            login_user(user)
            next_page = request.args.get('next')
            return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check email and password', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

All application quite have the same structure just using different `SECRETE_KEY`, `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` and another problem is when i have logout some of the application, all application also logout too, so how can i fix the problem.

Comment: Do your apps share the virtual environment?

Comment: Flask-login saves the current_user in LocalProxy instance which is kinda like environmental variable.

Comment: @kate-melnykova I think it not because each application were setup on different vm.

Comment: @kate-melnykova So are they any way to fix it?